# Operation order in obj1.method1(obj2.method2()).method3().method4(obj2.method5(obj2.method6())

Tags: java

Can somebody explain me the order of opperations here : obj1.method1(obj2.method2()).method3().method4(obj2.method5(obj2.method6())

Comment: those method are chained, think them as single operations, and think how to resolve every operation (so first you will have to resolve `method1`, but in order to call it, you have to pass a parameter, so you have to resolve `method2`, then you have `method3`...)

Answer (score 1):

below are operations sequences

```
op1 obj2.method2()
op2 obj1.method1( result of op1)
op3 (result of op2).method3()
op4 obj2.method6()
op5 obj2.method5(result of op4)
op6 (result of op3).method4(result of op5)
```

Comment: Shouldn't op 4 be the last operation (result of op3).method4(result of op6) ? We need to take argument the result of op 6

Answer (score 1):

**In this link, the priority of operation in java explained very well** https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/, according to that, operator ''." is invoked from the left to the right in the same level so firstly, this method must be invoked according to this fact
*Method1 → method3 → method3 → method 4*
but it is not true.

But there is another rule for invoking each method, its parameter must be determined before invoking the method, for example for invoking method 1, its parameter which is obj2.method2() must be determined so before invoking method 1, method 2 is invoked.

**according to this rule, the methods invoked with these orders:**

1. Method2
2. Method1
3. Method3
4. Method6
5. Method5
6. Method4

this phenomenon is named "method chaining" and the below link explains it a little bit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-chaining-in-java-with-examples/